# Asynchronous population of collection initializer

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, collection-initializer

I would like to populate a collection using collection initializer that will call async methods:

```
public class Diagnostics
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DiagnosticsInfo>> Get() => new List<DiagnosticsInfo>
    {            
        await GetDiagnosticsInfo1(),
        await GetDiagnosticsInfo2(),
        await GetDiagnosticsInfo3()
    };
}
```

The aim is for all the `GetDiagnosticsInfoX()` methods to execute in parallel.
I have a suspicion that the generated code will invoke  `GetDiagnosticsInfoX()` methods synchronously - it will await the first call before invoking the second.

Is my gut feel correct?

If so I assume I would need to await all the tasks like this:

```
public class Diagnostics
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DiagnosticsInfo>> Get()
    {
        var task1 = GetDiagnosticsInfo1();
        var task2 = GetDiagnosticsInfo2();
        var task3 = GetDiagnosticsInfo3();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

        return new List<DiagnosticsInfo> {task1.Result, task2.Result, task3.Result};
    }
}
```

Comment: Is my gut feel correct? yes. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my gut feel correct?

Your gut feeling is right. All collection initializer does is invoke the `Add` method for the collection. This means your code is translated to:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DiagnosticsInfo>> Get()
{
    var list = new List<DiagnosticsInfo>();         
    list.Add(await GetDiagnosticsInfo1());
    list.Add(await GetDiagnosticsInfo2());
    list.Add(await GetDiagnosticsInfo3());
    return list;
}
```

Using `Task.WhenAll` will wait for all async methods to complete. You can then return the array you receive:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DiagnosticsInfo>> Get()
{
    var task1 = GetDiagnosticsInfo1();
    var task2 = GetDiagnosticsInfo2();
    var task3 = GetDiagnosticsInfo3();

    return await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
}
```

Comment: ``return await Task.WhenAll()`` - nice

Comment: i think removing return is enough.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary What do you mean?

Comment: `return await` not works. compile time error. cannot convert void to Collection.Generics blah blah

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It would only be `void` if the return value from `GetDiagnosticsInfo` is a `Task`, which it isn't. It's a `Task<DiagnosticsInfo>`.